# sed - Replace string with special characters

Tags: string, shell, unix, sed

I want to replace the first string with the next

```
FindText[1]=/Folder 1/01. SubFolder/Demo(Object)

ReplaceText[1]=/Folder 1/01. SubFolder/02. SubFolder/Demo(Object)
```

I have tried this option with "`|`" but doesn't work.

```
>>sed -i 's|FindText[1]=/Folder 1/01. SubFolder/Demo(Object)|ReplaceText[1]=/Folder 1/01. SubFolder/02. SubFolder/Demo(Object)|g' filename.txt
```

The square brackets in the find expression doesn't seem to be found.

Comment: Square brackets are a regex special character and have to be escaped. I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: The duplicate is very general, but definitely covers your case.

Comment: Note that the duplicate covers a lot of territory. For the most part, `sed` uses POSIX BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax, though modern versions often have an option (`-E` and/or `-r`) to enable ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax. Additionally, you can match a newline with `\n`; in the GNU version but not all others, you can use `\n` in the replacement text as a newline. Some (many) versions of `sed` also feature extensions to the ERE syntax which get close to the BRE functionality, but with differences in notation (requiring backslashes before characters that an ERE would not need).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed -i 's|FindText\[1\]=/Folder 1/01. SubFolder/Demo(Object)|ReplaceText\[1\]=\/Folder 1\/01\. SubFolder\/02\. SubFolder\/Demo\(Object\)|g' filename.txt
```

special characters like \, [, ], (, ) and . must be escaped!